# Algorithm to fit people in a monthly calendar

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have an interesting algorithm to build and I have tried a couple of things but couldn't get it just right.

I have the following set of rules:

- 16 people to fill every day of the month (let's call it 28 days to make it even weeks)
- 4 people per day
- Each person should have a maximum of 7 days a month
- There has to be two days between each picked day (so if Person1 has a Monday, they shouldn't have another shift on Saturday-Sunday before nor Tuesday-Wednesday after)
- Each person should have a free weekend during the month (we include Fridays during weekends, so no shifts on Fri-Sat-Sun once)

What I've tried so far (there's not a lot of svelte-specific code, mostly js):

https://svelte.dev/repl/0fc5a8e1b2a241a9985950c6a0a1ec43?version=3.44.3

https://svelte.dev/repl/c66a7de71cda46ec94fc1e11811a6883?version=3.44.3

They are similar approaches, where the first one goes over each day in the range and tries to pick people one day at a time and the second one goes over people and tries to pick all of that person's days at once.

My issue with both of those approaches is that usually there will be days where not all people are selected.

Is there a way to improve the algorithm? Do I have another way to go about this?

Algorithm used for picking days by person

```
function getShiftsForPerson(person, days, existingShifts) {
const _existingShifts = [...existingShifts];
const shifts = [];

const shuffledDays = shuffle(days);

for (const day of shuffledDays) {
    if (shifts.length >= 7) break;

    // Get the shifts for the current week, starting Monday
    const firstDayOfWeek = startOfWeek(day, { weekStartsOn: 1 });
    const lastDayOfWeek = endOfWeek(day, { weekStartsOn: 1 });
    const shiftsForLastWeek = existingShifts.filter((shift) =>
        isWithinInterval(shift.date, {
            start: subWeeks(firstDayOfWeek, 1),
            end: subWeeks(lastDayOfWeek, 1)
        })
    );

    // Check if the person is unavailable on the given day
    const ruleForDay = person.rules.find((rule) => isEqual(rule.date, day));
    if (ruleForDay?.condition === 'unavailable') {
        continue;
    }

    // Check if there are available slots for the day
    const shiftsForDay = _existingShifts.filter((shift) => isEqual(shift.date, day));
    if (shiftsForDay.length >= PEOPLE_PER_DAY) {
        continue;
    }

    // Check if the person has shifts on the last two or next two days
    const shiftsForLastAndNextTwoDays = _existingShifts.filter(
        (shift) =>
            shift.person.name === person.name &&
            isWithinInterval(shift.date, { start: subDays(day, 2), end: addDays(day, 2) })
    );

    if (shiftsForLastAndNextTwoDays.length > 0) {
        continue;
    }

    // Check if the person worked on the same day last week
    const workedSameDayLastWeek = shiftsForLastWeek
        .filter((shift) => shift.person.name === person.name)
        .some((shift) => getDay(shift.date) === getDay(day));

    if (workedSameDayLastWeek) {
        continue;
    }

    // Check if the person already has 3 weekends shifts
    const shiftsForPerson = _existingShifts.filter((shift) => shift.person.name === person.name);
    if (isWeekend(day)) {
        const shiftsOnWeekends = shiftsForPerson.filter((shift) => isWeekend(shift.date));
        if (shiftsOnWeekends.length >= 3) {
            console.log(person.name, 'has 3 weekend shifts', format(day, 'dd/MM/yyyy'));
            continue;
        }
    }

    shifts.push({
        date: day,
        person
    });
    _existingShifts.push({
        date: day,
        person
    });
}

if (shifts.length < 7) {
    console.log(`Person ${person.name} has only ${shifts.length} shifts`);
}

return shifts;
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)?

Comment: Nice idea! I haven't so far, I'm not sure how I could go about breaking the problem down in another way

Comment: This question might not be a good fit for code review, we review working code to help you improve coding skills. Please read [Where can I get help?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: [cs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) might be helpful here. This is a [constraint satisfaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction) problem. Here's the DP notes from [MIT](https://web.mit.edu/15.053/www/AMP-Chapter-11.pdf) and [CMU](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~avrim/451f09/lectures/lect1001.pdf), you may find something like the problem. It kind of looks like a linear programme; in which case the [simplex algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm) would be great.